# How test test PWA on locally hosted webserver using physical Android device?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, android, certificate, https

I have a test webserver hosted locally (127.0.0.1), hosted with https (port 443).

(The webserver is hosted in Virtualbox, but I don't know if that matters).

The site is hosted using a *.[mySite].com (wildcard) certificate (valid purchased certificate).  I am able to access it locally (using a browser on my server), and the certificate works correctly.

I am developing a PWA, which I want to test locally on a physical Android device.

As I understand to get the PWA to be installable, I need to meet certain criteria (https://infrequently.org/2016/09/what-exactly-makes-something-a-progressive-web-app/)

According to that site, one of the requirements is "Originate from a Secure Origin. Served over TLS and green padlock displays (no active mixed content)."

I am trying to get my android device connected, but the "Originate from a secure origin" requirement is giving me trouble.

One thing I tried is to hook my phone via USB, using gnirehtet, then I could access the site using https://10.0.2.2

But, accessing the site via IP address makes my wildcard certificate invalid.  I tried editing the hosts file on my Android device to point mySite.com to 10.0.2.2, but I read that I'd need to root the device first.

Am I overthinking this?  Or is there an easier way to test my locally hosted PWA on my Android device?

Comment: If you install adb on the PC and enable Developer Options + ADB on device you can forward TCP ports through adb to the device when it is connected via USB.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that. and was able to take gnirehtet out of the equation.  But I'm still back at the same problem.  My device can access the site at https://localhost:8443, which forwards to the correct port on the server.  The page loads, but I still get a warning in Chrome that says the certificate does not match.  Is there a way to make that warning go away?  Or does it now matter when testing PWAs?  I thought it's required to have a green padlock according to the rules in the link I included above?

Comment: That may be possible using a local DNS server that assigns your server DNS name to localhost or alternatively a (non-intercepting) proxy that you configure on Android and that runs on your PC. But in tis case you wouldn't need the adb port forwarding.